# elasticsearch facet limit

Tags: java, elasticsearch, heap-memory, facet

I am using elasticsearch 0.20.2 on EC2 instance (16GB RAM, no swap enabled). I have a lot indexed documents and when I try to do facet results I got heap space error and elasticsearch server is unusable then. I was increasing heap memory for java but nothing helps. So my question is can I limit number of documents on which facet will be applied.

Here is my settings and mapping:

```
my_settings = {
    'settings': {
        'analysis': {
            'analyzer': {
                'text_analyzer': {
                    'tokenizer': 'standard',
                    'filter': ['standard', 'lowercase']
                },
                'suggestions_analyzer': {
                    'tokenizer': 'standard',
                    'filter': ['suggestions_shingle']
                }
            },
            'filter': {
                'suggestions_shingle': {
                    'type': 'shingle',
                    'min_shingle_size': 2,
                    'max_shingle_size': 5
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

my_mapping = {
    'test-type':{
        'properties':{
            'publish_datetime': {'type': 'date'},
            'text': {
                'type': 'multi_field',
                'fields': {
                    'text': {'type': 'string', 'analyzer': 'text_analyzer', 'include_in_all': True},
                    'suggestions': {'type': 'string', 'analyzer': 'suggestions_analyzer', 'include_in_all': False}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and my search query is:

```
query = {
    'filtered': {
        'filter' : {
            'limit' : {'value' : 10}
        },
        'query':{
            'prefix':{
                    'text.suggestions': 'wha'
            }
        },
    },
    'facets':{
        'text_suggestions':{
            'terms':{
                'field':'text.suggestions',
                'regex':'^%s.*' % 'wha',
                'size': 5
            }
        }
    },
    'size': 0
}
```

Is someone succeed to limit document number which will be facet let share with us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible to artificially limit the number of documents on which to run the aggregation -- that aggregation would clearly be incorrect. The facets are limited by the query you issue (and also by any facet_filters you use).

So, several ways to keep in mind:

- In general, facets will be limited by the `query` you send to Elasticsearch
- Values for fields you're faceting on will be loaded into memory
- There are some techniques to prevent out of memory errors for *ad-hoc* faceting, but they are not useful for regular user-exposed searching/faceting

Please see the [*Estimating field cache size for facets in advance*](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/elasticsearch/1N2qvxQkjB4) discussion on the mailing list.

Based on the query you have posted, it's not clearly what are you trying to do with faceting on the `text.suggestions` field?

Comment: So you are telling me that number of query results are input for facet. So if that is correct when i put size limit into query section then i don't get any facet result, and i know there are results from query cause same query with given size and executed standalone gives results. 'query':{
            'prefix':{
                    'text.suggestions': 'wha'
            },'size': 100
        },